# How to decode encoded text from a web page

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I have an API page of my school site and I want to parse the data from it but the page looks like this and I don't know how to decode this text using python.
(The encoded letters are cyryllic)

The data from the page(it looks like this even in the browser):

```
\u0421\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b, 15 \u0430\u043f\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044f.&nbsp;<br />\r\n\u0423\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u044f\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043e&quot; \u0432 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0438 \u0441 \u0442\u0435\u043c &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u0443\u0447\u0438\u043b\u0438&quot;, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a, \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0442\u043e \u0431\u044b \u0432\u044b \u0435\u0433\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0435 \u0437\u0430 5 \u043c\u0438\u043d\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u0441\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043b\u0438. \u041f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0447\u0438\u0432\u043e \u0438 \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e.
```

The data that I want to get:

```
Сдать после каникул, 15 апреля.&nbsp;<br />\r\nУбедительная просьба оформлять решение &quot;как положено&quot; в соответствии с тем &quot;как учили&quot;, а не так, будто бы вы его на коленке за 5 минут перед сдачей делали. Писать разборчиво и аккуратно.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Prepared by @APIuz team**

```
#For python3

import json
import io
text = '\u0421\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b, 15 \u0430\u043f\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044f.&nbsp;<br />\r\n\u0423\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u044f\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043e&quot; \u0432 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0438 \u0441 \u0442\u0435\u043c &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u0443\u0447\u0438\u043b\u0438&quot;, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a, \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0442\u043e \u0431\u044b \u0432\u044b \u0435\u0433\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0435 \u0437\u0430 5 \u043c\u0438\u043d\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u0441\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043b\u0438. \u041f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0447\u0438\u0432\u043e \u0438 \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e.'

io.open("APIuz.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8").write(json.dumps(text, ensure_ascii=False))
print(open("APIuz.txt", "r").read())

#For python2

print(repr(u'\u0421\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b, 15 \u0430\u043f\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044f.&nbsp;<br />\r\n\u0423\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u044f\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043e&quot; \u0432 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0438 \u0441 \u0442\u0435\u043c &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u0443\u0447\u0438\u043b\u0438&quot;, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a, \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0442\u043e \u0431\u044b \u0432\u044b \u0435\u0433\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0435 \u0437\u0430 5 \u043c\u0438\u043d\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u0441\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043b\u0438. \u041f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0447\u0438\u0432\u043e \u0438 \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e.').decode('unicode-escape'))

#The code is just what you think

#>>> u'Сдать после каникул, 15 апреля.&nbsp;<br /> Убедительная просьба оформлять решение &quot;как положено&quot; в соответствии с тем &quot;как учили&quot;, а не так, будто бы вы его на коленке за 5 минутперед сдачей делали. Писать разборчиво и аккуратно.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution in my case:

```
some_string.encode('utf-8').decode()
```